abq3Dmesh2geom and keyword error on mergeWire (Abaqus CAE)
I try to use the plug-in abq3Dmesh2geom.py from the Graz university (https://www.tugraz.at/en/institutes/iwb/studying/software/abaqus-cae/) on Abaqus CAE to convert a 3D orphan mesh in an unmeshed part.
The orphan meshes I want to convert in parts are a disk with a hole and an opened torus.
I opened Abaqus PDE, selected my path (c:/SIMULIA/CAE/2019/win_b64/code/python2.7/lib/abaqus_plugins/abq3Dmesh2geom.py) and launched it with "kernel" option.
The running script looped forever on this section :
######### create wire edges
print 'Generating Wires'
e=ypart.elementEdges
l=0
m=0
e20=len(e)/20
wiredata=[]
# read nodal data from ypart (copied model)
for i in range (0,len(e)):
    en=e[i].getNodes()
    points=[]
    for j in range (0,len(en)):
        points+=[en[j].coordinates]
    wiredata+=[points]

I tried another way, running the .py script by going in File > Run script...
I got the following error message :
File "C:/SIMULIA/CAE/2019/win_b64/code/python2.7/lib/abaqus_plugins/abq3Dmesh2geom.py", line 39, in <module> mergeWire=ON,meshable=ON,smoothClosedSpline=ON)
TypeError: keyword error on mergeWire

For now, I didn't find any documentation on "mergeWire" in Abaqus.
Don't hesitate to drop a message if you have any idea or tips to solve it.

You should try asking the owners of the library.
